# Not able to select item by typing inside combobox

Tags: extjs, filter, combobox

This is my second time I am posting the same question as did not get answer till now.

I have a combobox and following is the store (ExtJs 2.3)

**Combo Store:**
Assignments
Meetings
Salary

I am filtering the combo on key up so that 'Salary' item wont be diaplyed int he list and it works fine.
But as the combobox item can also be selected by typing iside combobox, I have written following code on keyUp and beforeQuery of the combo.

```
keyup: function () {
    combo2.selectedIndex = -1;
    combo2.store.clearFilter();
    combo2.store.filterBy(function (record) {
          return record.get('text') != 'Salary';
    });
}

beforequery: function (queryEvent) {
    var combo1Val = combo.value; // Give the selected value correctly
    if (combo1Val  ==  'Student' && combo2.store.isFiltered()) 
    {
        queryEvent.combo.expand();
        queryEvent.combo.onLoad();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This filters out the 'Salary' option successfully, but now I am not able to select any option by typing the inside combobox as before i.e. now if I type 'As', it is not selecting 'Assignment' option anymore. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try fiddle definitely i can help you

Comment: I am getting trouble setting up fiddle in extjs 2.3

Comment: on keyup don;t clear filter extjs automatically clears it. so your code should be combo2.store.filterBy(function (record) {
          return record.get('text') != 'Salary';
    });

Comment: comment this (combo2.store.clearFilter();) line and try it should work

Comment: I tried this, still the same issue

Comment: If you don't want "Salary" to be displayed/selected under certain conditions, why won't you just *remove* it from the store?

Comment: I dont want it for particular situation but want it on other situations

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using typeAhead?
something like this--

```
    {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                name: 'address',
                id: 'addressId',
                store: Ext.create('myStore'),
                valueField: 'fullAddress',
                displayField: 'name',
                minChars: 2,
                typeAheadDelay: 100,
                typeAhead: true,
                emptyText: 'Select Address',
                listEmptyText: 'error loading list!',
                width: 300
            }
```